# Pagenumbering in report

Tags: page-numbering

I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
```

with

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

and then the pages with

```
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables
```

are numbered (foot, in the middle). How to get rid of the numbers on these pages? On other "not automatically generated pages" it is ok without numbers.

Answer (score 4):

`\tableofcontents` and it's fellow commands `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` use a the `plain` pagestyle.  It's 'easy' to temporarily switch back to use `empty`, but it has to be restored afterwards, if page numbers are requested (for chapters etc.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}


\makeatletter
\let\latexps@plain\ps@plain   % Store definition
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty        % Use empty pagestyle (ps)
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables


\clearpage
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\latexps@plain   % restore pagestyle 'plain' 
\makeatother


\chapter{First}

\end{document}
```

Alternative solution with `xpatch` package:

has to be restored afterwards, if page numbers are requested (for chapters etc.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\xapptocmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\listoffigures}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\listoftables}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables



\chapter{First}

\chapter{Second}


\end{document}
```

Note, that both methods will clear page headers too.

Comment: Thank you, the first one works. After \tableofcontents etc. I would like to restore pagestyle 'headings'. It works using

Comment: \makeatletter
\let\ps@headings\latexps@headings   % restore pagestyle 'plain' 
\makeatother

Comment: But, the numbers disappear on every 'first chapter' page. On these pages I would also like to have the page number top left (as in 'headings').